# Build a C program from a C++ program

Tags: c++, c, c++11

So, What I want to do: Basically I want to build a C/C++ program (ready to execute) from another c++ program (main program).

Let's take this example:
main.cpp

```
int main()
{
   //do something
   //there I will modify source of program which I want to build 
   sourceCode = ""; //maybe from a file
   //then a function like this:
   buildProgramFromSource(sourceCode, "program.exe");
}
```

Source of program which I want to generate from main.cpp

```
int main()
{
    //do another thing
    int value1 = value From main.cpp
    int value2 = value frim main.cpp too
}
```

So, I have source stored on main.cpp, and I want to modify that source then build that program.

How should I implement this?

Or, maybe there is any other way to generate a .exe program from a main C++ program?

Later edit: Assuming that environment doesn't have any compiler installed. The compiler should be integrated on main program.

In other words I don't want to use functions like **system()** or **shellexecute** which are using compilers from environment.

The application will be used under Windows.

An example would be very usefully.

Comment: Well, you either need to call the compiler (for example using `system`) or include a compiler into your project?

Comment: (I do this quite regularly at work, since I work with OpenCL, and basically that is C running on a graphics processor [or on the CPU if you like] - but OpenCL already has a `clCreateProgramFromSource` function, so I don't need to worry about how to write one - and yes, that means we have a whole C compiler built into the application)

Comment: Now, you probably need to be more specific about what you are actually "not able to do".

Comment: There are many dedicated tools, some with domain-specific languages, for this exact purpose.  I cannot recommend rolling your own unless it's for a learning exercise.  I can recommend [cmake](http://www.cmake.org/cmake-tutorial/) or [waf](http://docs.waf.googlecode.com/git/apidocs_16/tutorial.html).

Comment: You are building a partial evaluator!

Comment: Depending on what you want to do this for, the easiest solution might just be a shell script.  The first thing the shell script would do is run your program, and then the second thing would be to invoke g++ (or whatever compiler you prefer) on the .cpp file that was created by your program.

Comment: Assuming that I want to include the compiler into my project. The ideal result should be a simple application without dependencies like compiler installed.

Comment: It is **operating system specific**

Comment: Windows. The app will be used under Windows. I need something to start, a book, a link or anything which will point me on right direction.

Comment: You are trying to open a bigger can of worms than you can swallow. What is your *real* problem?

Comment: There is not a real problem. I just want to understand how could I do this... .

Answer (score 2):

It is **operating system specific**. And things are different if the second (built) program is a standalone program or a library (or some code loaded by the first).

On Linux (and other Posix systems), you can generate a C or C++ file (by using usual text output functions; I recommend building in memory some [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) of the generated C++ file). Then you can run some C++ compiler on it by forking a process (in the simple case, use [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) or [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html), or use the lower level [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) & [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html), etc....). See [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) for more.

Then you could dynamically load the obtained shared object with [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) and retrieve some symbols (function pointers) using `dlsym`

#### Linux details

- compile and link the main program with `-rdynamic` i.e. `g++ -Wall -g -rdynamic main.cc -o prog` ; the `-rdynamic` flag is needed to make the program functions visible from the loaded code. It is useful to declare the signature of loaded functions and to declare global function pointers, like:

  ```
   typedef int somefun_t (const std::string&);
   somefun_t *globfun;
  ```
- generate at runtime a C++ file `genfoo.cc` with functions to be accessed by the main program declared as `extern "C"`.
- fork a compilation into a shared object ([shared library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_%28computing%29#Shared_libraries)) with position independent code: so run from inside your program: `g++ -Wall -fPIC -g -O -shared genfoo.cc -o genfoo.so`
- call `dlopen` and `dlsym` from your main program (notice that `dlopen` do weird things if you pass it a filename without any `/`):

  ```
    void* hdl = dlopen("./genfoo.so", RTLD_NOW);
    if (!hdl) 
      { std::cerr << "dlopen:" 
                  << dlerror() << std::endl; exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
    globfun = dlsym(hdl, "func");
    if (!globfun) 
      { std::cerr << "dlsym func:" 
        << dlerror() << std::endl; exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
  ```
- use the function pointer `globfun` as you need, e.g.

  ```
  std::string s;
  int r = (*globfun) (s);
  ```
- if you are serious you should `dlclose(hdl)` before exiting.

If you just want to compile and run a *different* program things are much simpler: just compile the generated program as usual (`gcc -Wall -g genfoo.cc -o genprog`) and execute it as usual (`system`, `fork` +  `execve`, ....)

If the target system does not have any C compiler (but consider also [tinycc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_C_Compiler) which is able to compile from a string -containing C code- in memory with its `libtcc`), you cannot do that. You need to use some [JIT compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) library like [libjit](http://www.gnu.org/software/libjit/), [GNU lightning](https://www.gnu.org/software/lightning/), [asmjit](https://github.com/kobalicek/asmjit). .... Alternatively consider embedding some scripting interpreter like [Lua](http://lua.org/) or [Guile](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile)

#### Windows details

I don't know Windows, but it is rumored to have equivalent [dynamic loading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_loading) functionality, e.g. [LoadLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). If you want to avoid running a C compiler at runtime, you'll also need some JIT library. Details are different (`dllexport`)

Some frameworks or libraries ([Poco](http://pocoproject.org/), [Qt](http://qt-project.org/), [Boost](http://boost.org/) ....) are providing system-neutral wrappers for these dynamic loading features.

---

NB: On Linux you can practically do a *lot* of `dlopen` (hundreds of thousands), see [manydl.c](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/manydl.c). My [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) system (a domain specific language to extend [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)) is generating C++ code and `dlopen`-ing it on the fly.

Notice also that some programming languages, like [Common Lisp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_lisp) (and also [Meta-Ocaml](http://okmij.org/ftp/ML/MetaOCaml.html)), are much more suited for runtime [evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eval) & [meta-programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming) ([multi-staged](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-stage_programming)). Notably its [SBCL](http://sbcl.org/) implementation of Common Lisp is able to compile arbitrary expressions then run them at runtime! See also [J.Pitrat's blog](http://bootstrappingartificialintelligence.fr/WordPress3/).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would likely be including a standalone compiler in your program's files that are distributed. When the program needs to be recompiled:

1. Create another copy of the original main.cpp source on the system

   - Something like: `system("copy main.cpp new_main.cpp");` on windows
2. Open a stream to `new_main.cpp` (assuming your code named the new copy `new_main.cpp`)
3. Append your additional code to the end/beginning of the file
4. Flush and close the output stream
5. Call your compiler and pass it the path to the new file

   - If you're using g++, for example, you would write something like: `g++ new_main.cpp -o new_main.exe`
   - If you use the Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler, you can access it by running `system("vcvarsall");` (found in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC` for me) followed by `system("cl 'path/to/project/new_main.cpp');` (found in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin` for me).

After this you have `new_main.exe` which is the compiled form of `main.cpp` + some extra code.

**Warning:** This option will require that you either install the compiler or include its necessary files if you distribute the application. You do not need to install/include them with `new_main.exe`, but you will need to install/include them with the program that compiled `new_main.exe`.

---

If you want to compile from memory, the process is similar:

1. Open a stream to `main.cpp`
2. Read `main.cpp` to a char buffer (assuming `main.cpp` only contains ASCII characters)
3. Close the stream to `main.cpp`
4. Append your code to the start/end of the buffer (**make sure you have room in the buffer!**)
5. Call your compiler library

   - This call is dependent on your compiler library, but similar to: `compileCode(String_Version_Of_Code_Read_From_File);`

---

As an extra bit of information, if you are in a situation where you need to to dynamically modify and build a program, there's typically better solution. This is not always the case, but usually there is a better approach.

A third option could be writing your own compiler, but I would highly advise against that.